# Python : Word frequency using itertools.chain

Tags: python

I'm trying to find word frequencies in a document using below code. However, instead of word frequency, this returns character frequency. Can some one explain why? I'm following an article from which I got this code, but I'm unable to validate since the output hasn't been shown.

```
sentence1 = [token for token in "hello how are you".split()]
sentence2 = [token for token in "i am fine thank you".split()]
print(sentence1)
from collections import Counter
import itertools

def map_word_frequency(document):
    print (document)
    return Counter(itertools.chain(*document))
word_counts = map_word_frequency((sentence1 + sentence2))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the call to [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

sentence1 = [token for token in "hello how are you".split()]
sentence2 = [token for token in "i am fine thank you".split()]


def map_word_frequency(document):
    return Counter(chain(*document))


word_counts = map_word_frequency([sentence1, sentence2])

print(word_counts)
```

**Output**

```
Counter({'you': 2, 'hello': 1, 'how': 1, 'are': 1, 'i': 1, 'am': 1, 'fine': 1, 'thank': 1})
```

From the documentation, you have the following example:

```
chain('ABC', 'DEF') --> A B C D E F
```

So, when:

```
chain(*document)
```

is executed, it unpacks the list and pass each element of the list as an individual argument. A more concrete example:

```
document = ['bad', 'bat', 'baby']
chain(*document)
```

is equivalent to:

```
chain('bad', 'bat, 'baby')
```

If you want to use chain, remove the concatenation `sentence1 + sentence2` and pass instead a list of list, `[sentence1, sentence2]`, like:

```
def map_word_frequency(document):
    return Counter(chain(*document))


word_counts = map_word_frequency([sentence1, sentence2])

print(word_counts)
```

Also notice that is preferred to use [chain.from_iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), for the above example, as in:

```
Counter(chain.from_iterable(document))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make sense of using `chain`, you'd have to use it like this:

```
Counter(itertools.chain(sentence1, sentence2))
```

or

```
document = itertools.chain(sentence1, sentence2)
Counter(document)
```

The standard list concatenation `lst1 + lst2` that you use makes `chain` obsolete. You are then applying it to an unpacked list of strings, resulting in an iterator over chars. And btw,

```
[token for token in s.split()]
```

is the same as just

```
 s.split()
```